# OpenMP/C++ How to get openMP loop to increment by a variable size

Tags: c++, openmp

I am trying to read an image using openMP. The image is large(32141*17453) and I want to read it chunk wise.I am very new to openMP and not sure if it can solve the problem.About what I am not sure is..

1)Can I increment like j+=chunksize?

2)Can I give threads different chunks to process.

3)If I cannot process chunkwise and have to go looping through height and width,how do I store such a huge data.I have tried using vector of vectors but it is not an optimal solution.

Kindly help.

I have tried to get the code working but results are not correct.However if I put a lock surrounding the ReadImagePixelChunkWise I get the result but it serializes the execution.It would really help to have a critical code feedback as well so I can get to know what I am doing really wrong.

```
#pragma omp parallel shared(nHeight,nWidth,nColorBands) 
private(id,chunksize,i,j,k)
{
    id = omp_get_thread_num();
    for(i=0;i<nColorBands;i++)
    {
        float *fPixelBlockData = new float[nWidth];
#pragma omp for
        for(j=0;j<nHeight;j+=chunksize)
        {
            ReadImagePixelChunkWise(fPixelBlockData);
        }
    }
}
```

The code doesnot work correctly but when I do something like...

```
for(j=0;j<nHeight;j++)
{
    omp_set_lock(&lck);
    ReadImagePixelBlockAPI(fPixelBlockData);
    omp_unset_lock(&lck);
}
```

It works correctly.The chunkwise reading works with serializing but performance lag is too much.
It takes almost around 5-6 minutes on an intel i5 3.20 Ghz 8 Gb Ram windows machine.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. The right question is: Is `ReadImagePixelChunkWise` threadsafe. Judging by the interface and your problems the answer is: Probably not. So there's nothing to do about parallelizing your code without digging into that function - which you have not provided in the question.

Comment: Where are you reading the image from? Read speed is more likely to be the bottleneck than processor speed.

Comment: Hi Zulan, Thanks for the insight.ReadImagePixelChunkWise is an API which we use,but we dont have code access.The API looks something like ReadImagePixelChunkWise(READ_FLAG,blocksize,width,DataToBeFilled);  
What I do here is in serial code pass a chunk of rows as blocksize and the whole width.What it does is returns my DataToBeFilled with all the pixel values.

Comment: If there isn't even a handle for the image, it's still *probably* not threadsafe. In any case - guessing is bad - refer to the documentation of this proprietary function or contact the one who provides it with respect to the question of thread safety.

Comment: @Zulan.There is a handle to the image.Actually something like                           io_Dataset *imagedataset; io_colorTable *pColorTable;                                                                                        imagedataset->open(FLAG_READ);  //it gets all the info about image                          pColorTable->getcolorBand(1);                                                                                   As we can see we do call the API like this                                         imagedataset>ReadImagePixelChunkWise(READ_FLAG,blocksize,width,fPixelBlockData);

Comment: @DDrmmr..Thankyou for the reply.I am reading from an API provided by a separate custom I/O Engine.I agree that read speed is the bottleneck since it gets executed serially.Actually I was hoping of a way to get this done concurrently.Regards.

Comment: The API function you use probably reads sequentially chunks from a file. If you call it simultaneously from two or more threads, it is likely to return garbage as the I/O calls will overlap. Functions that support reading in parallel usually require that you supply an offset for each operation and not rely on a file pointer as sequential reading does.